# I struggle to find a code to estimate the second derivative of sin(x) at x=pi/4 with h^-1 in octave

Tags: matlab, function, octave

I tried function handle as follow:

```
f=@(f(x+h)-2*(f(x))+(f(x-h)))./h^2;
```

I got parse error:

> invalid parameter list

```
f=@(f(x+h)-2*(f(x))+(f(x-h)))./h^2;
```

I try to estimate the second derivative of sin(x) at x=pi/4 with h^-1 in octave.

I couldn't find code to estimate the second derivative of sin(x) at x=pi/4 with h^-1

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous functions are defined as:

```
f= @(parameters)(function);
```

You forgot to add the parameters. 
I suspect you want:

```
f=@(x)((f(x+h)-2*(f(x))+(f(x-h)))./h^2);
```

However this will cause a second problem: you are overwriting `f`. Maybe you want

```
% you defined some f=@(x)...
g=@(x)((f(x+h)-2*(f(x))+(f(x-h)))./h^2);
```

Comment: Thanks for shedding light but I get persisting errors when I put value of x and h

Comment: @SurendaSekatane cant help unless you show the code for the error